# Using shooting method to solve DE of fourth order

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a fourth-order differential equation using the shooting method and I wrote the following code, But this code does not work for me and I don't know what the problem is.

```
a = 1.3; M = 0.3; S = 1;

shooting[{s1_?NumericQ, s2_?NumericQ}] := 
  Module[{sol, Fsol}, 
   sol = NDSolve[{F''''[
        t] = (a/(a + 1)) S (t F'''[t] + 3 F''[t] + F[t] F''[t] - 
           F[t] F'''[t]) + (M a/(a + 1)) F''[t], F[0] == 0, 
      F'[0] == s1, F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2}, {F}, {t, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {F[0] == 0, F'[0] == s1, 
         F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2}}];
   
   Fsol = F /. sol[[1]];
   Fsol[1]];

shootingResults = FindRoot[shooting[{s1, s2}], {{s1, 0}, {s2, 0}}];

s1Final = s1 /. shootingResults
s2Final = s2 /. shootingResults

h = 0.01; n = 100; grid = Range[0, 1, h]; coeff = (a/(a + 1));

eqns = {F''''[
     t] = (a/(a + 1)) S (t F'''[t] + 3 F''[t] + F[t] F''[t] - 
        F[t] F'''[t]) + (M a/(a + 1)) F''[t]};

bcs = {F[0] == 0, F'[0] == s1Final, F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2Final};

sol = NDSolve[{eqns, bcs}, {F}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteDifference", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "Coordinates" -> {grid}}}];

Plot[Evaluate[F[t] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "F[t]"]
```

Comment: Let's start by looking at the error message: `NDSolve: Equation or list of equations expected instead of ...` Now look at the first equation in your `NDSolve`, it uses `=` (Set) instead of `==` (Equal). Use `Quit` to clear all variables, then change that `=` to `==`. Second, you cannot use `FindRoot` for two variables.

Comment: Because all the boundary conditions are at `t = 0`, this is an initial value problem, but the Shooting method is for boundary value problems.  If, in fact, you actually are trying to solve a boundary value problem, you need to include some boundary conditions at `t = 1` in `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're trying to solve a fourth-order differential equation using the shooting method in Mathematica. I've reviewed your code, and it looks mostly correct. However, there's one issue in your code. In your `shooting` function, you're trying to extract s1 and s2 from the `shootingResults` using `s1Final = s1 /. shootingResults` and `s2Final = s2 /. shootingResults`. However, you should use `s1Final = s1 /. shootingResults[[1]]` and `s2Final = s2 /. shootingResults[[2]]` to access the solutions properly.

Here's the corrected code:

```
a = 1.3; M = 0.3; S = 1;

shooting[{s1_?NumericQ, s2_?NumericQ}] := 
  Module[{sol, Fsol}, 
   sol = NDSolve[{F''''[
        t] == (a/(a + 1)) S (t F'''[t] + 3 F''[t] + F[t] F''[t] - 
           F[t] F'''[t]) + (M a/(a + 1)) F''[t], F[0] == 0, 
      F'[0] == s1, F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2}, {F}, {t, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {F[0] == 0, F'[0] == s1, 
         F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2}}];
   
   Fsol = F /. sol[[1]];
   Fsol[1]];

shootingResults = FindRoot[shooting[{s1, s2}], {{s1, 0}, {s2, 0}}];

s1Final = s1 /. shootingResults[[1]];
s2Final = s2 /. shootingResults[[2]];

h = 0.01; n = 100; grid = Range[0, 1, h]; coeff = (a/(a + 1));

eqns = {F''''[
     t] == (a/(a + 1)) S (t F'''[t] + 3 F''[t] + F[t] F''[t] - 
        F[t] F'''[t]) + (M a/(a + 1)) F''[t]};

bcs = {F[0] == 0, F'[0] == s1Final, F''[0] == 0, F'''[0] == s2Final};

sol = NDSolve[{eqns, bcs}, {F}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteDifference", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "Coordinates" -> {grid}}}];

Plot[Evaluate[F[t] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "F[t]"]
```

Comment: The code gave the following errors:   `FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[shooting[{s1,s2}],{{s1,0},{s2,0}}].`

Comment: `ReplaceAll::reps: {shooting[{s1,s2}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.`

Comment: Is this an AI-generated answer? If it is, please know that it is strongly advised against posting such answers.